# How to make a pull request from the repository I forked to the original

Tags: git, github

Steps I've followed: Set up git and account on github, forked a repository for assigments I have to do, and currently following this guide: https://help.github.com/articles/creating-a-pull-request/

I forked succesfully and modified a file in MY repository, which is a fork of the original. I now want to pull the changes to the original so that they get approved or denied.

The problem is I don't understand the concept and nothing shows up, following those steps, which makes sense because I try to pull into the original master and it tells me there are no differences so there's nothing to update (because the change is in my forked repository).

What concept am I missing? Because right now I'm not even sure the operation i should do is a pull since when looking for more info nothing shows up.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You can [pull request across forks](https://help.github.com/articles/creating-a-pull-request-from-a-fork/).

1. Go to the origin repo
2. click new pull request
3. click compare across forks
4. select the forked version of the repo that you made and
5. create the PR.